# Need a C# example for MCAPI.Net

Tags: c#, mailchimp, mcapi

MCAPI.Net (http://mcapinet.codeplex.com/) is for connecting the MailChimp API with a subscription form on a website. I have seen PHP and VB.Net examples of how to subscribe people. I need a C# one. Can anyone help?

Comment: I tried that already.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if you still need it but I have a small wrapper for MCApi :

```
public class MailingService : IMailingService
{
    public bool RemoveSubscriber(string email, string list, string apiKey, bool deleteMember = true)
    {
        var mcApi = new MCApi(apiKey, true);
        var unsubscribeOptions = new List.UnsubscribeOptions();
        unsubscribeOptions.SendGoodby = false;
        unsubscribeOptions.SendNotify = false;
        unsubscribeOptions.DeleteMember = deleteMember;
        try
        {
            return mcApi.ListUnsubscribe(list, email, unsubscribeOptions);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool AddOrUpdateSubscriber(string email, string list, string apiKey)
    {
        var mcApi = new MCApi(apiKey, true);
        var merges = new List.Merges();
        var subscriptionOptions = new List.SubscribeOptions();
        subscriptionOptions.UpdateExisting = true;
        subscriptionOptions.DoubleOptIn = false;
        subscriptionOptions.SendWelcome = false;
        return mcApi.ListSubscribe(list, email, merges, subscriptionOptions);
    }

    public bool AddOrUpdateSubscriber(string email, string list, string apiKey, string firstName, string lastName, string title, string company, string guid)
    {
        var mcApi = new MCApi(apiKey, true);
        var merges = new List.Merges();
        merges.Add("FNAME", firstName);
        merges.Add("LNAME", lastName);
        merges.Add("TITLE", title);
        merges.Add("COMPANY", company);
        merges.Add("GUID", guid);
        var subscriptionOptions = new List.SubscribeOptions();
        subscriptionOptions.UpdateExisting = true;
        subscriptionOptions.DoubleOptIn = false;
        subscriptionOptions.SendWelcome = false;
        return mcApi.ListSubscribe(list, email, merges, subscriptionOptions);
    }

    public bool AddOrUpdateSubscriberPromo(string email, string list, string apiKey, string firstName, string lastName, string title, string company, string interests, string guid)
    {
        var mcApi = new MCApi(apiKey, true);
        var merges = new List.Merges();
        merges.Add("FNAME", firstName);
        merges.Add("LNAME", lastName);
        merges.Add("TITLE", title);
        merges.Add("COMPANY", company);
        merges.Add("GUID", guid);
        merges.Add("INTERETS", interests);
        var subscriptionOptions = new List.SubscribeOptions();
        subscriptionOptions.UpdateExisting = true;
        subscriptionOptions.DoubleOptIn = false;
        subscriptionOptions.SendWelcome = false;
        return mcApi.ListSubscribe(list, email, merges, subscriptionOptions);
    }

    public bool UpdateSubscriberEmail(string oldEmail, string newEmail, string apiKey)
    {
        var mcApi = new MCApi(apiKey, true);
        var merges = new List.Merges();
        var subscriptionOptions = new List.SubscribeOptions();
        subscriptionOptions.UpdateExisting = true;
        subscriptionOptions.DoubleOptIn = false;
        subscriptionOptions.SendWelcome = false;
        return mcApi.ListUpdateMember().ListSubscribe(list, email, merges, subscriptionOptions);
    }

    public bool SendCampaign(string url, string urlParams, string fromEmail, string fromName, string list, string emailSubject, string camapaignTitle, List<string> emails, string apiKey)
    {
        var mcApi = new MCApi(apiKey, true);
        var options = new Campaign.Options(list, camapaignTitle, fromEmail, fromName, fromName); 
        var content = new Campaign.Content.Html();

        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var segmentName = "qi_" + guid;

        var segmentId = 0;

        if(segmentId == 0) segmentId = mcApi.ListStaticSegmentAdd(list, segmentName);
        mcApi.ListStaticSegmentMembersAdd(list, segmentId, emails);

        var segmentIds =  new List<string>();
        segmentIds.Add(segmentId.ToString());

        var condition = new Campaign.SegmentCondition("static_segment", "eq", segmentIds);
        var conditions = new MCList<Campaign.SegmentCondition>();
        conditions.Add(condition);

        var segmentOptions = new Campaign.SegmentOptions(Campaign.Match.AND, conditions);

        content.Url = url;

        var success = false;

        LogManager.GetLogger(GetType().FullName + " " + camapaignTitle).Info("Test de campagne" + " / Nb emails : " + emails.Count + " / Url : " + url);

        try
        {
            var id = mcApi.CampaignCreate(Campaign.Type.Regular, options, content, segmentOptions);
            LogManager.GetLogger(GetType().FullName + " " + camapaignTitle).Info("Création de campagne - " + id);
            try
            {
                success = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && mcApi.CampaignSendNow(id);
                LogManager.GetLogger(GetType().FullName + " " + camapaignTitle).Info("Envoi de campagne - " + id + " Statut : " + success + " / Nb emails : " + emails.Count + " / Url : " + url);
                return success;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogManager.GetLogger(GetType().FullName + " " + camapaignTitle).Fatal(string.Format("Erreur lors de l'envoi d'une campagne {0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager.GetLogger(GetType().FullName + " " + camapaignTitle).Fatal(string.Format("Erreur lors de la création d'une campagne {0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
        }

        return success;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the code here - http://mcapinet.codeplex.com/discussions/271278. Person on thread says they are having problems with it, but at least it's a start.